# Train Stanford custom NER model

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am creating a custom ner train model for Italian language. I am using Stanford 3.6 compiled on 2015-12-09  .

I get an error running the command to train the model:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer stanford_al_korpus.txt > jane-austen-emma-ch1.tok
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:42)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.tok(PTBTokenizer.java:424)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.main(PTBTokenizer.java:768)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

Wht can I do ?

Comment: You are simply missing the dependency of Slf4j in your class path, down load the jar and correct java -cp stanford-ner.jar slf4j.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer stanford_al_korpus.txt > jane-austen-emma-ch1.tok
For any other dependency related errors try the same :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded stanford-ner, and found this issue, then run,

```
java -cp lib/*:stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer file.txt > file.tok
```

Because you need to include the dependencies ,which are Slf4j .jar files